# Dual norm of a truncated and ordered (decreasing order) $\ell_1$-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I do not understand yet how the following dual-norm of a truncated and ordered (in decreasing fashion) $\ell_1$-norm $\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert_{[k]}$ on $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^n$ is:

$$\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert^*_{[k]}= \max\left\{\frac{1}{k} \| \mathbf{x} \|_1,\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert_{\infty}\right\}$$

The  truncated $\ell_1$-norm is defined as the sum of the $k$ largest magnitudes of the entries in $\mathbf{x}$ vector, i.e., $\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert_{[k]}=\lvert x_{i_1}\rvert+.....+\lvert x_{i_k}\rvert$ in which $\lvert x_{i_1}\rvert\geq\lvert x_{i_2}\rvert\geq.....\geq\lvert x_{i_n}\rvert$.

Thank you

Comment: I've never heard this referred to as the "truncated $\ell_1$ norm." Interesting. It has a logic to it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Sure, I can change the definition of a dual norm as you have suggested.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my other comment---I was having trouble getting LaTeX to work. Your definition is fine, I just think it might help you find a proof to use a different one.

Comment: No problems. Is the following definition of a dual norm be useful?

$\left\| \mathbf{y} \right\|^*_{[k]} = \max_{\left\| \mathbf{z} \right\| \leq1} {\rm Re} \ \left\{ \mathbf{z}^{\rm H} \mathbf{y} \right\}$

Comment: I tend to use $\le 1$ but yes!

Comment: ok, thank you. I will think more about it.

Comment: I certainly don't see how Hölder applies here—except as it informs the dual relationship of the $\ell_1$ and $\ell_\infty$ norms.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will remove that question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest proof I can think of is the following:

1. Prove that $\|\cdot\|_{[k]}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{[k]}^*$ are norms (easy be definition).
2. Use the LP problem suggested by Michael Grant that 
   $$
   \|x\|_{[k]}=\max\{x^Tz\colon \|z\|_1\le k,\,\|z\|_\infty\le 1\}
   $$
   and since $\|z\|_1\le k$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\frac{1}{k}\|z\|_1\le 1$ rewrite it as
   $$
   \|x\|_{[k]}=\max\{x^Tz\colon \|z\|_{[k]}^*\le 1\}.\tag{1}
   $$
3. The relation (1) means by definition that $\|\cdot\|_{[k]}$ is the dual of $\|\cdot\|_{[k]}^*$. Taking dual once again: the dual of $\|\cdot\|_{[k]}$ is the second dual of $\|\cdot\|_{[k]}^*$, which is the same as $\|\cdot\|_{[k]}^*$.

---

P.S. The last fact "the second dual norm is the norm itself" is a known result in finite dimensional spaces (even in reflexive Banach spaces). A proof normally uses separation theorems of convex sets (alternatively Hahn-Banach theorem). It can be found in e.g. Horn, Johnson, Matrix Analysis, Ch. 5, Sec. 5.5.

Comment: I tend to agree with this proof without deep diving into details.

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally derived the dual norm of your dual norm. Let us first derive some conjugate functions:
$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \max\left\{g(x),h(x)\right\} \\
g(x) &= \frac{1}{k} \| x \|_1 \\
h(x) &= \lVert x\rVert_{\infty} \\
g^*(y) &= 0 \text{ if } k \| y \|_\infty \leq 1 \;(\infty \text{ otherwise}) \\
h^*(y) &= 0 \text{ if } \| y \|_1 \leq 1 \;(\infty \text{ otherwise}) \\
\end{align}
$$
Using the well-known rule for the conjugate of $\max\{g,h\}$, we get:
$$\begin{align}
f^*(y) &= \inf_{v,z} \{ (z_1g)^*(v) + (z_2h)^*(y-v) \mid z_1+z_2 = 1, z\geq 0 \}\\
&= 0 \text{ if } \exists v,z : k \| v \|_\infty \leq z_1, \; \| y-v \|_1 \leq z_2, \; z_1+z_2 = 1, z\geq 0 \\
&= 0 \text{ if } \exists v : k \| v \|_\infty +\| y-v \|_1 \leq 1 \;(\infty \text{ otherwise})
\end{align}$$
Using that the convex conjugate of a norm is [the indicator of the unit ball for the dual norm](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/conj.pdf), the dual norm of the dual norm is
$$||y||^{**} = \inf_v \{ k \| v \|_\infty +\| (y-v) \|_1 \}.$$
This does not equal the norm you started with. Either the truncated L1-norm is not a real norm, or I made a mistake. Maybe you could do the same analysis for the norm itself, or check the above for a possible mistake.

Comment: Are you sure it's not equal?

Comment: And yes, it's a norm.

Comment: Convince yourself that this optimization problem has an optimal value of $\|x\|_{[k]}$:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize}_v & v^T x \\
\text{subject to} & \| v \|_1 \leq k \\
                  & \| v \|_\infty \leq 1 \\
\end{array}$$
Take the dual of this with respect to $v$ and I'm reasonably sure you'll get your answer, or something very close to it.

Comment: @MichaelGrant If I dualize your problem I get exactly my solution. The reason I think it's wrong because I checked it numerically and the values are not equal (your problem has the correct value, mine does not).

Comment: How convinced are you, then, that my model is correct? Because if you are, then the problem is with your numerical verification ;-)

Comment: In CVX, this is called `norm_largest(x,k)`, and it is implemented as `sum_largest(abs(x),k)`. I constructed the implementation of `sum_largest` using a similar dual model (because the primal model is not jointly convex in $x$ and $v$).

Comment: @MichaelGrant that is also how you can derive conditional value at risk. Found the error in my numerical verification.

Comment: Yes! And it's not _just_ that the primal model isn't jointly convex; it's also that with graph implementations, you need convex functions to be described by minimizations and concave functions by maximizations.

Comment: @LinAlg and Michael Grant:
Thank you for your inputs. 

I must admit that I am not grasping all the details yet (hopefully, I will be able to understand more of it over time). I am sure all the conjugate stuff is trivial for you and can easily manipulate. I apologize for asking basic and fundamental things here since I am at very basic level. 
I think I understand a bit of the formulation of the problem (because of my level of understanding of optimization for now). Then Michael says "take the dual w.r.t. $v$". So my basic question is how to do that? Form Lagrangian?

Comment: @LinAlg and Michael Grant:
How Michael's formulated problem (after taking dual!?) is equal to LinAlg's solution. How did you approach that? I would appreciate so much if you can teach me bit pedagogically.

Comment: @user550103 you can take the dual of Michael's problem using the Lagrangian or by first writing it as a linear optimization problem. Try both approaches, it takes practice.

Comment: @LinAlg Thanks. But I don't know how to find the derivatives of $\ell_\infty$ norm and $\ell_1$ norms (they are not differentiable!?). Probably use the indicator functions that you have utilized above. Then, I feel like hitting a wall again :( . Probably I will just try to live with your above derivation of dual of a dual norm, which should be equivalent to this 'overloaded truncated' $\ell_1$ norm.

Comment: @user550103 try for for than 15 minutes yourself, or look at Appendix A.1.6 of the book by Boyd and Vandenberghe.

Comment: You don't need to take derivatives, certainly, but you do have to know how to find the conjugate of a norm. That is, the conjugate of a norm is the indicator function of the unit ball induced by the dual norm. Or, per LinAlg's suggestion, convert the norm constraints to a set of linear inequalities and equations and do it that way.

Comment: @MichaelGrant and LinAlg: Thank you for your suggestions. I must also add that I am preparing for my linear algebra exams. My level of understanding of Convex optimization is very basic level. I got this question from old problem sets in linear algebra. It seems that this problem is very hardcore convex optimization problem than linear algebra problem. I feel like that I am lacking all the necessary "toolset" to solve this by myself yet. I really appreciate your time and efforts to solve and guide me. Thank you so much.

Comment: @LinAlg and MichaelGrant, I am sorry to re-continue on this thread. I want to try to obtain the dual of this ordered and truncated $\ell_1$-norm with your support, if you have time. I would highly appreciate that. 

Based on your suggestions, I have been trying to learn the dual of this truncated 1-norm. I have made some attempt. I am still missing something, but probably close enough (if everything is correct)!?  Thank you so much in advance

Comment: @MichaelGrant: I am trying to work on the solution based on your and LinAlg feedback. I would be happy to receive your comments as well, if you have time. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Based on the input from @LinAlg and MichaelGrant--to be reviewed.

The function $f(\mathbf{x}) = \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_{[k]}$ is equal to the optimal value of the following linear program (LP):
\begin{align*}
\text{maximize}_\mathbf{v} \quad &\mathbf{v}^{\rm T} \mathbf{x}\\
\text{subject to }\quad & \lVert \mathbf{v} \rVert_1 \leq k \\
&  \lVert \mathbf{v} \rVert_\infty \leq 1
\\
\equiv 
\\
\text{minimize} \ \ \quad &-\mathbf{v}^{\rm T} \mathbf{x}\\
\text{subject to }\quad & \mathbf{1}^{\rm T} \mathbf{t}  \leq k  \ ; - \mathbf{t} \preceq \mathbf{v} \preceq \mathbf{t} \\
                        &  - \mathbf{1} \preceq \mathbf{v} \preceq \mathbf{1} \\
\equiv 
\\
\text{minimize} \ \ \quad &-\mathbf{v}^{\rm T} \mathbf{x}\\
\text{subject to }\quad & \mathbf{1}^{\rm T} \mathbf{t}  \leq k  \\
                        & - \mathbf{t} \preceq \mathbf{v} \preceq \mathbf{t}\\
                        &  \mathbf{t} \preceq \mathbf{1} \\
\equiv
\\
\text{minimize}     \ \ \quad &-\mathbf{v}^{\rm T} \mathbf{x} &\\
\text{subject to }\quad & \mathbf{1}^{\rm T} \mathbf{t} - k \leq 0  \\
                        &  -\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{t} \preceq 0 \\
                        &  \mathbf{v} - \mathbf{t} \preceq 0 \\
                        &  \mathbf{t} - \mathbf{1} \preceq 0 
\end{align*}

Then, forming the Lagrangian such that
\begin{align*}
L\left(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{t},\rho,\boldsymbol{\mu}_1,\boldsymbol{\mu}_2,\boldsymbol{\lambda} \right) 
&= -\mathbf{v}^{\rm T} \mathbf{x} +\rho \left( \mathbf{1}^{\rm T} \mathbf{t} - k \right) + \boldsymbol{\mu}_1^{\rm T} \left( -\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{t} \right) + \boldsymbol{\mu}_2^{\rm T} \left( \mathbf{v} - \mathbf{t} \right) +  \boldsymbol{\lambda}^{\rm T}\left( \mathbf{t} - \mathbf{1} \right) \\
&= -\mathbf{v}^{\rm T} \mathbf{x} +\rho \left( \mathbf{1}^{\rm T} \mathbf{t} - k \right) - \mathbf{v}^{\rm T} \boldsymbol{\mu}_1 - \mathbf{t}^{\rm T} \boldsymbol{\mu}_1  + \mathbf{v}^{\rm T} \boldsymbol{\mu}_2 - \mathbf{t}^{\rm T}  \boldsymbol{\mu}_2  + \mathbf{t}^{\rm T} \boldsymbol{\lambda} - \mathbf{1}^{\rm T} \boldsymbol{\lambda} \\
&= \mathbf{v}^{\rm T} \left( -\mathbf{x} -\boldsymbol{\mu}_1 + \boldsymbol{\mu}_2  \right) +  \mathbf{t}^{\rm T} \left(   \rho \mathbf{1} - \boldsymbol{\mu}_1 -  \boldsymbol{\mu}_2 + \boldsymbol{\lambda} \right) + \left( - \rho k  - \mathbf{1}^{\rm T} \boldsymbol{\lambda} \right) .
\end{align*}

Now, taking the derivative of $L\left( \mathbf{v},\mathbf{t},\rho,\boldsymbol{\mu}_1,\boldsymbol{\mu}_2,\boldsymbol{\lambda}\right)$ with respect to $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{t}$ such that the dual function reads
\begin{align*}
 g\left(\rho,\boldsymbol{\mu}_1,\boldsymbol{\mu}_2,\boldsymbol{\lambda}\right) &=
 \left\{ 
   \begin{matrix}
     \left( - \rho k  - \mathbf{1}^{\rm T} \boldsymbol{\lambda} \right) &  &   \left( -\mathbf{x} -\boldsymbol{\mu}_1 + \boldsymbol{\mu}_2  \right) = \mathbf{0} , \quad \rho \mathbf{1} - \boldsymbol{\mu}_1 -  \boldsymbol{\mu}_2 + \boldsymbol{\lambda} = \mathbf{0} \\
    -\infty   &  &\text{otherwise}.    
  \end{matrix} 
 \right.
\end{align*}

The dual optimization problem would be
\begin{align*}
\text{maximize} \quad \ & - \rho k  - \mathbf{1}^{\rm T} \boldsymbol{\lambda} \\
\text{subject to }\quad & -\boldsymbol{\mu}_1 + \boldsymbol{\mu}_2 = \mathbf{x} \\
&   \boldsymbol{\mu}_1 +  \boldsymbol{\mu}_2 = \rho \mathbf{1} + \boldsymbol{\lambda} \\
&  \rho \geq 0 \\
&  \boldsymbol{\mu}_1 \succeq 0 \ ; \ \boldsymbol{\mu}_2 \succeq 0\\
&  \boldsymbol{\lambda} \succeq 0 .
\\
& \equiv\\
\\
\text{minimize} \quad \ &  \rho k  + \mathbf{1}^{\rm T} \boldsymbol{\lambda} \\
\text{subject to }\quad & -\boldsymbol{\mu}_1 + \boldsymbol{\mu}_2 = \mathbf{x} \\
&   \boldsymbol{\mu}_1 +  \boldsymbol{\mu}_2 = \rho \mathbf{1} + \boldsymbol{\lambda} \\
&  \rho \geq 0 \\
&  \boldsymbol{\mu}_1 \succeq 0 \ ; \ \boldsymbol{\mu}_2 \succeq 0\\
&  \boldsymbol{\lambda} \succeq 0 .
\end{align*}

At the optimality, $\boldsymbol{\mu}_1 = \max \left\{0, -\mathbf{x} \right\}$ and $\boldsymbol{\mu}_2 = \max \left\{0, \mathbf{x} \right\}$ such that $| \mathbf{x}| = \rho \mathbf{1} + \boldsymbol{\lambda}$. Thus, the above optimization problem can succinctly be written as
$$\min_{\rho \geq 0,\: \boldsymbol{\lambda} \succeq 0} \left\{ \rho k  + \mathbf{1}^{\rm T} \boldsymbol{\lambda} \  : \ \left|\mathbf{x}\right| = \rho \mathbf{1} + \boldsymbol{\lambda}  \right\}.$$

[to be verified] To connect it with the dual function $f^*(\mathbf{x}) = \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_{[k]}^*$, we need to verify numerically.

Comment: @LinAlg: Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried to follow it and simplified (hopefully without any mistakes). On the other hand, for me, it is still a mystery (at least to me) how to relate it with your dual results yet :(.

Comment: You have $\min_{\rho,\lambda \geq 0}\{ k\rho + \sum \lambda_i : |x_i|=\rho+\lambda_i\}$. I agree it's not that simple to relate this to the dual norm.

Comment: Sorry, I might be bit slow. How did you obtain $\left|\mathbf{x}\right| = \rho \mathbf{1} + \boldsymbol{\lambda}$? From these two constraints (a) $ -\boldsymbol{\mu}_1 + \boldsymbol{\mu}_2 = \mathbf{x} $ and (b) $ \boldsymbol{\mu}_1 +  \boldsymbol{\mu}_2 = \rho \mathbf{1} + \boldsymbol{\lambda} $? If yes, then how?

Comment: Yes, from those constraints. They resemble a well known reformulation for absolute values. At optimlity, $\mu_1 = \max\{0,-x\}$ and $\mu_2 = \max\{0,x\}$. Let's remove some outdated comments to keep this thread readable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. I guess then we need to compare numerically.

Comment: Do you really need all this to prove that those two norms are dual? If your write you first line LP equivalently as $\|x\|_{[k]}=\max\{v^Tx\colon \|v\|_{[k]}^*\le 1\}$, the norm duality becomes evident by definition ([dual of the dual is the original norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_norm#Mathematical_Optimization)). Maybe I miss the point of this long discussion.

Comment: @A.Γ.: Thank you for your feedback. The question is to show that the dual-norm of a truncated and ordered (in decreasing order fashion) $\ell_1$-norm $\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert_{[k]}$ on $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^n$ is:
$$\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert^*_{[k]}= \max\left\{\frac{1}{k} \| \mathbf{x} \|_1,\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert_{\infty}\right\}$$.

Comment: @A.Γ. : We (I) would be happy to receive a sweet and short way to answer the main question.

Comment: @user550103 If you *accept* that the dual of the dual norm is back the primal one without proof (as a known result) then the answer to your question is short (see my comment above).